# Sybase 16 startserver failed due to missing libsapcrypto.so

Tags: linux, sybase

We've installed Sybase 16 Express in our Linux box, it was able to startup right after the installation. When we recently try restarting it with the startserver -f RUN_FILE command, it failed to find the libsapcrypto.so file.

```
    ~/sap/ASE-16_0/bin> ../sap/ASE-16_0/bin/dataserver: error while loading shared libraries: libsapcrypto.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

We searched this file, multiple matches presented in the following paths:

```
./DM/OCS-16_0/lib3p/libsapcrypto.so
./DM/OCS-16_0/lib3p64/libsapcrypto.so
./DM/OCS-16_0/devlib3p64/libsapcrypto.so
./DM/OCS-16_0/devlib3p/libsapcrypto.so
./DM/REP-16_0/lib64/libsapcrypto.so
./DataAccess/ODBC/lib/libsapcrypto.so
./DataAccess64/ODBC/lib/libsapcrypto.so
./OCS-16_0/lib3p/libsapcrypto.so
./OCS-16_0/lib3p64/libsapcrypto.so
./OCS-16_0/devlib3p64/libsapcrypto.so
./OCS-16_0/devlib3p/libsapcrypto.so
```

Comment: Most likely you didnt have all the appropriate environment variables set when you tried to restart it. You usually need to set variables like $SYBASE, $SYBASE_ASE, $PATH and $LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the correct directories for your installation. https://answers.sap.com/questions/11968291/why-do-we-need-to-setup-sybase-environment-variabl.html

Comment: Hi Rich, I ran the SYBASE.sh under the $SYBASE and $SYBASE/DM/ dirs, still have the same issue with the startserver command i.e. cannot find the libsapcrypto.so

Comment: It would still appear that $SYBASE/$SYBASE_OCS/lib3p and $SYBASE/$SYBASE_OCS/lib3p64 aren't in your $LD_LIBRARY_PATH - you might need to add those to fix it manually.

Answer (score 3):

Since this hasn't been answered yet, running this command worked for me:

```
. /opt/sap/SYBASE.sh
```

Note the different syntax to make sure the environment variables are set in the terminal session, as opposed to using this syntax:

```
/opt/sap/SYBASE.sh
```